# Why taking component out of return makes additional React rerenders?

Tags: reactjs

My initial code was:

```
<Container>
  <Carbs defaultCollapsed/>
  <Citrus defaultCollapsed/>
  <Gluten defaultCollapsed/>
</Container>
```

let's say `Carbs`, `Gluten` and `Citrus` have similar structure of:

```
<Carbs>
  <Collapsible defaultCollapsed={defaultCollapsed}>
    <List/>
  </Collapsible>
</Carbs>
```

it worked perfectly fine. But I needed to take out components from `Container` and generate them based on passed config. My code now looks like:

```
const CarbsOption = ({defaultCollapsed}) => <Carbs defaultCollapsed={defaultCollapsed}/>
const GlutenOption = ({defaultCollapsed}) => <Gluten defaultCollapsed={defaultCollapsed}/>
const CitrusOption = ({defaultCollapsed}) => <Citrus defaultCollapsed={defaultCollapsed}/>

const options = ['gluten', 'carbs', 'citrus']

const componentList = {
  gluten: {
    collapsed: true,
    component: GlutenOption,
    },
  citrus: {
    collapsed: true,
    component: CitrusOption,
    },
  carbs: {
    collapsed: true,
    component: CarbsOption,
    },
}

return(
  <Container>
    {
      options.map((option,i) => {
        const Component = componentList[option].component;
        return <Component key={i} defaultCollapsed={componentList[option].collapsed}/>
      })
    }
  </Container>
)
```

Main idea, is that components will be rendered based if they are in `options` array. Components are rendering fine, but once I uncollapse component and change one of the list selection in lets say `Carbs`, it triggers its parents to get rerendered and it causes component to collapse again. Why it's happening once I took code out of main `return`? And how to prevent extra rerenders so that collapsed state won't get updated on `List` change?

Comment: See my answer, I think that might be the solution, though I'm not 100% sure. Also, just fyi you can use `Object.values(componentList).map(...)` instead of creating a separate `options` variable :)

Comment: I'd like to see how the 'uncollapse' method looks like and what's doing. Also the whole component with the options. Does it use a useContext, useState etc. I'm guessing that uncollapsing an option triggers something that the parent listens to.

Comment: `Collapsible` component just allows you to collapse/uncollapse main content `onClick`

Comment: This is because when you move the components to the body of your functional component, it is called **at every render**. You should memoize the 3 functions: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: What gets to me is once I put back code in main `return` it works! Same components that stop working properly once taken in separate `const`

Comment: Terry, how can I wrap in `memo` lets say `Carbs`? Since I need to pass props as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your child components are being re-rendered is because they are being defined in the body if your functional component, meaning that they will be re-instantiated every single time your functional component re-renders. A quick fix will be to [memoize them using `React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), which will prevent unnecessary re-rendering:

```
const CarbsOption = React.memo(({defaultCollapsed}) => <Carbs defaultCollapsed={defaultCollapsed}/>);
const GlutenOption = React.memo(({defaultCollapsed}) => <Gluten defaultCollapsed={defaultCollapsed}/>);
const CitrusOption = React.memo(({defaultCollapsed}) => <Citrus defaultCollapsed={defaultCollapsed}/>);
```

However this feels a bit too verbose of my liking: since you are only swapping out the **name** of the component, why not just assigned it to a memoized variable?

```
const componentList = {
  gluten: {
    collapsed: true,
    component: Gluten,
    },
  citrus: {
    collapsed: true,
    component: Citrus,
    },
  carbs: {
    collapsed: true,
    component: Carbs,
    },
}
```

This will map your functional components `Carbs`, `Gluten` and `Citrus` directly to your template without needing an unnecessary layer of memoization.

Comment: Alternatively you could just bring the `const CarbsOption =` declaration (and others) outside of the Parent Component's body, at the top level of the file. Or would that not work in this instance?

Comment: That would also work, but if the child component needs access to certain states, refs, or etc from the parent component without being passed as a prop, then it has to live somewhere inside of it.

Comment: In some cases I'll need to do some maths like dividing list in different parts/filtering. Is it better to memoize `CarbsOption` or should I add memoized export to `Carbs` component?

Comment: It’s really up to you, but using memo will of course add an overhead compared to directly using the imported component in your array of objects.

Comment: Strange, it didn't work. I'll look more into it, but it keeps collapsing anyway.

Comment: Looks like memoization didn't work for me because `Collapsible` had `List` as a child. Found this article about memoization: https://gist.github.com/slikts/e224b924612d53c1b61f359cfb962c06

Comment: Solution for me was to get rid of components and turn them into functions instead that would return html.

Comment: @Alyona I don't think that's the cause, as you're not using the `children` prop at all...

Comment: Can `List` located inside of `Collapsible` be considered child? Even after using `React.memo` when I change `List`, `Collapsible` would rerender as well.

Answer (score 0):

**edit: This answer was based off an earlier version of the question and is not correct, but leaving it up for posterity.**

You should set a `key` for each component you render as part of a `map`. See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for details.

```
options.map((option, index) => {
    const Component = componentList[option].component;
    return <Component key={index} defaultCollapsed={componentList[option].collapsed}/>
})
```

(Note, the link I provided states `We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change`, but that's only important when the data you're mapping from changes, in which case you could have a stable key be part of the data. For something like this where the data is static, index is fine)

edit: To improve/simplify it a bit, I'd actually recommend getting rid of your `options` variable and doing this:

```
Object.entries(componentList).map(([componentName, options]) => (
    <options.component 
       key={componentName}
       defaultCollapsed={options.collapsed}
    />
)
```

Comment: My bad, index was there, I just forgot to write it in example. Any other reason why once taken out of main `return` too many rerenders start happening?

Comment: In that case, Elzoy's comment on your question is likely the route to pursue. If something about your `Carbs` component changes a parent state (by changing context, or changing a redux state that a parent listens to, or..?) then that would cause a rerender of the parent.

Comment: @Alyona also see my edit for how to minimize the code in your `map` call, though that won't fix your issue.